# grep fails with variable but works if variable is spelled out

Tags: grep, regular-expression

I have two comma delimited files

I will read 1 line from file 1,

I need to find matching lines in file2 including the comma's in between

If I do it literally by typing the line (i.e. copy-n-paste with mouse) I get what I need

If I assign the line to a variable, I get nothing

I'm stumped. I know I am doing something wrong as far as regex matching goes but what ?

Here is an example:

```
$ pattern=$(head -1 accts.csv)
$ echo $pattern
_ccc_net_pfx,_ccc_net_pfx_export
$ grep "$pattern" all.csv
$ grep "_ccc_net_pfx,_ccc_net_pfx_export" all.csv
MyDomain\user1,User-1,Administrator,_ccc_net_pfx,_ccc_net_pfx_export,owner,Application,,
MyDomain\user2,User-2,User,_ccc_net_pfx,_ccc_net_pfx_export,readonly,Application,,
```

Comment: You can help yourself and answerers by running `set -x`, running that sequence of commands again, and [edit]ing the question to show that too.

Comment: Works for me. As said, try running with the `xtrace` option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `$pattern` variable contains spaces -- or maybe a spurious `^M` / `CR` / `\r` at the end if `accts.csv` comes from a windows machine.

You can't see the spaces with `echo $pattern`, because the variable is not quoted (as it is in the call to grep), and so it's nicely split and trimmed by the IFS mechanism. Try something like `echo "{$pattern}"` instead.

You should trim it yourself:

```
$ pattern=$(sed 's/[ \r]//g;q' accts.csv)
```

Comment: It was not the spaces but the <CR> (^M) character at the end of each line. Coming from Excel export I presume as I exported these few minutes ago. Once the ^M characters trimmed, it works fine. Thank you for your suggestion and directing me to the correct path